# Does the spelling of "brainy" change when suffix is added?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which is the correct form, "brainyency" or "brainiency" - when the suffix "ency", which describes the condition of being "brainy" is added?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much, Nicole and Jas! 
Your clarification is very helpful :)

Alex

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/braininess), the condition of being brainy is **braininess.**

Answer (score 1):

Though there's no such word as "brainiency" valid derivations of brainy would require the y to change to an i; e.g. "brainier"